# Matrices vs Vectors in representing quantum states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, linear-algebra, density-operator

Typically, quantum states are represented by vectors in Hilbert space. However, I learned that one can also represent states using density matrices. Is there any reason to prefer one over the other? Furthermore, if matrices are used to represent states, what represent observables, since normally they are also represented by matrices?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, density matrices are a generalization, which has the advantage that they can also represent mixed states, while state vectors only describe pure states. So density matrices are useful in two cases: when you have an entangled state and want to consider a subsystem of the entangled system, or when the initial state of the system is not perfectly known.

Comment: ... or when you want to get rid of the phase ambiguity of pure state.

Answer (score 2):

Density matrices are a good way of representing quantum systems. The diagonal terms represent the probabilities of getting each state while the off diagonal terms represent coherence of the states.

For example if $|\psi\rangle = a|0\rangle+b|1\rangle$,then

\begin{eqnarray}
\rho = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|
\end{eqnarray}

This gives density matrix to be

\begin{pmatrix}
|a|^2 & ab^* \\
a^*b & |b|^2  
\end{pmatrix}
See how easy it is to represent a state in form of a matrix. Other benefit is that We can represent mixed states as well as pure states by density matrix

> Furthermore, if matrices are used to represent states, what represent observables, since normally they are also represented by matrices?

To represent states, we use vectors such as
\begin{pmatrix}
0  \\
1   
\end{pmatrix}
and observables are represented matrices

Answer (score 1):

Density matrices allow you to describe systems that are described by probabilities, which cannot be done with a single state vector. Lets say you want to model a system with constant classical probabilities for any expectation value that should remain constant at all times. One might think that this can be done with a superposition state, but that is not the case. Let
$$
|\psi\rangle = c_1|A\rangle +c_2|B\rangle,
$$
$\hat H|A\rangle=E_A|A\rangle$ and $\hat H|B\rangle=E_B|B\rangle$. The time dependency of this state is given by
$$
|\psi(t)\rangle =\exp(-iE_At/\hbar )c_1|A\rangle +\exp(-iE_Bt/\hbar )c_2|B\rangle,
$$

Now lets look at the expectation value of an operator $\hat O$,
$$
O(t) = \langle \psi(t)|\hat O|\psi(t)\rangle = |c_1|^2\langle A| \hat O|A\rangle +|c_2|^2\langle B|\hat O|B\rangle +c_1c_2^*\exp(-i(E_A-E_B)t/\hbar )\langle B|\hat O | A\rangle +c_1 ^*c_2\exp(i(E_A-E_B)t/\hbar )\langle A|\hat O|B\rangle \\
=|c_1|^2 O_A +|c_2|^2 O_B+2\Re [c_1c_2^*\exp(-i(E_A-E_B)t/\hbar )\langle B|\hat O | A\rangle].$$
Lets assume for simplicity that $c_1=c_2=1/\sqrt 2$ and that $\langle B|\hat O | A\rangle=O_{AB}\in \Re$, such that
$$
O(t) = 1/2 O_A + 1/2 O_B + O_{AB}\cos((E_A-E_B)t/\hbar )
$$

The take-aways is that the expectation value $O(t)=\langle \psi(t) |\hat O| \psi(t) \rangle $of this superposition state oscillates with frequency $\omega_{AB}=E_A-E_B/\hbar$ and amplitude $O_{AB}$ around the average value of $1/2(O_A+O_B)$. You do not measure the expectation values $O_A$ and $O_B$ with a probability of 50% at all times, and no superposition state allows you to  construct such a state, for all possible operators.

This is where the density matrix/operator formalism comes in. The formalism allows us  to define the following system
$$
\hat \rho = |c_1|^2 |A\rangle \langle A| + |c_2|^2|B\rangle \langle B|=1/2(|A\rangle \langle A| + |B\rangle \langle B|)\\
\hat \rho(t) = \exp(-i\hat H t/\hbar )\hat \rho \exp(i\hat H t /\hbar ) = \hat \rho
$$
The system characterized by this density operator will always give you 50% probability to find $O_A$ and 50% $O_B$ when you do a single measurement. The expectation value is independent of time and always $$\text{Tr}[\hat O \hat \rho(t)]=1/2(O_A+O_B)$$
Notice the lack of an oscillating term. You cannot construct a pure system without the oscillating coherences for a general operator, while the density operator formalism allows you to do so. The measurements of this density operator can be interpreted as a mixture of 50 percent in state A and 50 % percent in state B, which is different to a system in a pure quantum superposition state of A and B.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid unnecessary mathematical complications, let us consider a finite dimensional (complex) Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. The space of of all linear operators $A: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ will be denoted by $L(\mathcal{H})$.  For each $A \in L(\mathcal{H})$, its adjoint $A^\dagger \in L(\mathcal{H})$ is defined by the property $\langle \phi |A \psi \rangle=\langle A^\dagger \phi | \psi \rangle$ for all $\phi, \psi \in \mathcal{H}$. The hermitian operators, satisfying $A^\dagger = A$, constitute an important subclass of $L(\mathcal{H})$. The eigenvalues of a hermitian operator are real numbers.

In a physical context, each *observable* $\mathcal{A}$ is represented by an associated hermitian operators $A$. The eigenvalues of $A$ are the possible measurement values of the observable $\mathcal{A}$.

In full generality, a *state* is defined as a mapping $\omega: L(\mathcal{H}) \to \mathbb{C}$ satisfying $$\begin{align} \omega(\lambda_1 A_1 + \lambda_2 A_2) &=\lambda_1 \omega(A_1) + \lambda_2 \omega(A_2)  \quad \forall \,  A_{1,2}  \in L(\mathcal{H}), \,\,  \forall \, \lambda_{1,2} \in \mathbb{C},  \,   ({\rm linearity}) \tag{1.1}\label{eq1.1}\\ \omega(A^\dagger A) & \ge 0 \quad  \forall A \in L(\mathcal{H}), \qquad   ({\rm positivity}) \tag{1.2}\label{eq1.2}\\ \omega(\mathbf{1})&= 1. \qquad \qquad \qquad ({\rm normalization}) \tag{1.3}\label{eq1.3}\end{align}$$ With an operator $A=A^\dagger$ representing an observable $\mathcal{A}$, $\omega(A)$ is interpreted as the expectation value of the observable $\mathcal{A}$ in the state $\omega$.

Each normalized vector $\psi \in \mathcal{H}$ (with $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle=1 $) defines a state $\omega_\psi$ via $\omega_\psi(A) := \langle \psi|A \psi \rangle$ for all  $A \in L(\mathcal{H})$, obviously satisfying the above conditions. States of this type are called *pure states*. States that cannot be written in this form are called *mixed states*.

It is also easy to check that an arbitrary *convex* linear combination of pure states, $$ \omega = \sum\limits_k p_k \, \omega_{\psi_k}, \quad p_k \gt 0, \quad \sum\limits_k p_k =1, \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$ defines a (mixed) state (the positive numbers $p_k$ are "classical" probabilities). The decomposition \eqref{eq2} of the mixed state $\omega$ is not unique. In fact, there are infinitely many ways to represent a given mixed states $\omega$ as a convex linear combination of pure states. A convenient standard representation of a state $\omega$ is provided by its *density operator* $\rho_\omega \in L(\mathcal{H})$. It can be shown that for any given state $\omega$ one can always find an operator $\rho$  with the properties $$ \rho^\dagger = \rho  \ge 0, \quad {\rm Tr} \rho =1, \quad \omega(A) = {\rm Tr}(\rho A) \quad \forall \, A \in L(\mathcal{H}). \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$ The non-negative hermitian operator $\rho$ has an orthonormal basis $\{ \phi_1, \phi_2, \ldots \phi_n\}$ ($n = {\rm dim}\mathcal{H}$) of eigenvectors $\phi_k \in \mathcal{H}$ ($\rho \phi_k = \rho_k \phi_k$) with eigenvalues  $\rho_k \ge 0$, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \rho_k=1$ and the spectral representation $$ \rho = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \rho_k | \phi_k \rangle \langle \phi_k | \tag{4}\label{eq4},$$ such that the trace in \eqref{eq3} can be written as $$\omega(A) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \rho_k \langle \phi_k | A \phi_k \rangle \tag{5}\label{eq5}.$$ The density operator of a pure state, $\omega_\psi (A) = \langle \psi | A \psi \rangle $, is simply given by the one-dimensional projection operator $\rho_\psi = | \psi \rangle \langle \psi |$. A density operator describing a *pure* state is characterized by the property $\rho_\psi^2 = \rho_\psi$.

As an example, let us consider a spin $1/2$ system with the two-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^2$. The pure state described by the state vector $$ \psi= \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \tag{6}\label{eq6}$$ (spin in positive $z$-direction) has the density matrix $$ \rho_\psi = \psi \psi^\dagger = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}. \tag{7}\label{eq7}$$ The pure state described by the state vector $$ \phi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \tag{8}\label{eq8}$$ (spin in positive $x$-direction) has the density matrix $$ \rho_\phi = \phi \phi^\dagger = \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}. \tag{9}\label{eq9}$$ On the other hand, the maximally mixed state has the density matrix $$ \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}  + \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{1}_2 /2. \tag{10}$$

Answer (score 0):

You never *have to* use a state matrix, and this is called the *purification* of the state matrix and its existence is the subject of the [Schrödinger-HJW theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%E2%80%93HJW_theorem).

However it is really handy to use state matrices whenever you can. State matrices have the following nice properties

- Evolution is still linear, just like it was for wavefunctions
- Expectations are still linear, just done with a trace instead of an inner product. The trace has a handy cyclic permutation law so that you can still argue that e.g. for $U$ unitary, $\operatorname{Tr}[U^\dagger \rho U] = \operatorname{Tr}[\rho U U^\dagger]  = \operatorname{Tr}[\rho]$ etc, so you can kind of see that the Heisenberg and Interaction pictures are especially easy to derive using such a rule.
- The evolution equation is allowed to have an imaginary commutator which is  "Hamiltonian-like" and some "Lindbladian" terms that act like continuous quantum measurements. So you get a nice unification of unitary evolution and nonunitary evolution in one formalism.
- Because the purification of the state matrix requires a larger Hilbert space, you have the potential to understand systems that *do not conserve energy*. Dissipation is a part of the system! So for example if you want to understand *lasing*, you can do a qualitative treatment in terms of explaining population inversion, but since there is energy leaving the lasing cavity the proper understanding of what state it settles on and why, is presumably given by state matrices.

On the other hand dealing with state matrices generally requires a bunch of techniques of carefully applied **approximations**. Just to give a flavor of why this is necessary, the purified state is evolving unitarily, presumably has a Poincaré recurrence time, and so *any* dissipative assumption about the subsystem is technically incorrect. In fact even if you manage to deal with a large coupling system in thermal equilibrium, the "constant temperature" situation, you should be able to derive a fluctuation-dissipation theorem where the thermal sink that you're dropping energy into, causes noisy disruptions to your quantum states by the inverse coupling. And this is a direct manifestation of a Poincaré recurrence, the noise will eventually reassemble a state arbitrarily similar to the original.

So there is a real art involved in simplifying state matrix results enough to get useful theory results out of them, without oversimplifying them so much that they fail to describe the universe.