Unpolarized spin 1/2 particles
The desity matrix for the unpolarized spin 1/2 particles is given by
$\rho= 1/2\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$
A single spinor cannot be ascribed to it. Some sort of summing and averaging is required. Anyone can help me with its derivation.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/750649

I think it can not be derived. In quantum mechanics, we define the state of system as a unit vector $|\Psi\rangle$ in a Hilbert space. Observables are operators acting over this Hilbert space and both state vectors and operators can be used to calculate expectation values
$$
\langle O \rangle = \langle \Psi|O|\Psi\rangle.
$$
Since the states are defined at least of a global phase factor, this is completely equivalent to define projector states $|\Psi\rangle\!\langle \Psi|$ and
$$
\langle O \rangle = \text{tr}(O|\Psi\rangle\!\langle\Psi|)
$$
The formulation in terms of projectors has one advantage: we can define statistical mixing of two or more states. The most general state, then, not a projector, but a density matrix
$$
\rho = \sum_i p_i |v_i\rangle\!\langle v_i| \quad p_i \geq 0, \sum_i p_i = 1.
$$
Now if you accept this formulation, it is easy to accept the totally mixed state. For $1/2$ spins, such density matrices are 2x2  matrices that can be written in terms of Pauli matrices
$$
\rho = \frac{1}{2}\left(\mathrm{I}+ \langle \sigma_x\rangle \sigma_x + \langle \sigma_y\rangle \sigma_y + \langle \sigma_z\rangle \sigma_z\right)
$$
Now, the coefficients of the expansion above are exactly the expectation values of the respectively Pauli matrices, which in turn are associated with the expectation value of spin in that direction
$$
\langle S_j \rangle = \frac{\hbar}{2}\langle \sigma_j\rangle
$$
Which should be zero in all directions of the unpolarized state. Setting all expectation values to zero in the expansion of $\rho$ above, we get
$$
\rho = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{I}
$$

As I understand the expectation values of $\sigma$  would corresspond  $p_i$. The identity matrix and the coefficient of 1/2 seems to have been added to get the correct answer. As is known any 2x2 matrix can be written using the four matrices which includes the identity. How can the identity matrix inclusion and the factor 1/2 be justified?

Ok  1/2 cause trace has to be 1.
